# CSS filter Gray is not happen in the image hover

Tags: html, css

Using css i try to convert `image` from colour to black and White. But its not happen in the top of the another div.

My code shown below

```css
.home-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-center-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home-center img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
}

.home-center img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="home-center">
    <div class="home-center-text">
      <h2>our film</h2>
      <span>See our work</span>
    </div>
    <img src="http://reussis.com/demo/studio/images/Home_Our_Film.jpg" class="img-responsive">

  </div>
</div>
```

Sample test link https://jsfiddle.net/rijo/29eo2kkL/1/

Comment: FF v54. I see gray image and on hover it's colored. What is wrong than?

Comment: If u hover in the text div it wont't work why? how to solve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `:hover` not to image, but to wrapper:

```css
.home-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-center-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home-center img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
}

.home-center:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="home-center">
    <div class="home-center-text">
      <h2>our film</h2>
      <span>See our work</span>
    </div>
    <img src="http://reussis.com/demo/studio/images/Home_Our_Film.jpg" class="img-responsive">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this happens? It should work on img too, right? Or is it about the display property?

Answer (score 0):

**Use `:hover` on wrapper no `img` :**

```
.home-center:hover img{
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```css
.home-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-center-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home-center img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
}

.home-center:hover img{
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="home-center">
    <div class="home-center-text">
      <h2>our film</h2>
      <span>See our work</span>
    </div>
    <img src="http://reussis.com/demo/studio/images/Home_Our_Film.jpg" class="img-responsive">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger effects on another element based on `hover` of another element. Like this.

```
.home-center-text:hover ~ .home-center-img 
{  /* Do stuff here */ }
```

```css
.home-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-center-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home-center-img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
}

.home-center-img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.home-center-text:hover ~ .home-center-img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="home-center">
    <div class="home-center-text">
      <h2>our film</h2>
      <span>See our work</span>
    </div>
    <img src="http://reussis.com/demo/studio/images/Home_Our_Film.jpg" class="img-responsive home-center-img">

  </div>
</div>
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered).